# How to call a stored procedure in EF Core 3.0 via FromSqlRaw

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

I recently migrated from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.0.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to call a stored procedure that returns an entity.

In EF Core 2.0 it was possible:

```
var spParams = new object[] { "bla", "xx" };
var createdPath = ModelContext.Paths.FromSql("AddNodeWithPathProc  @p0, @p1", spParams).Single();
```

In EF Core 3.0 the method `FromSQL` is replaced with `FromSqlRaw`. However, I didn't manage to successfully call a stored procedure and then process the value. This is useful when the stored procedure inserts data into the database.

So in EF Core 3.0, I use this code:

```
var createdPath = ModelContext.Paths.FromSqlRaw("AddNodeWithPathProc @p0, @p1", spParams).Single();
```

but it will throw an exception, because the generated SQL is invalid and looks something like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(2) [p].[PathId], [p].[Level], [p].[NodeId], [p].[NodePath], [p].[NodePathString]
FROM (
     @sql @p0, @p1
) AS [p]',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000), @sql nvarchar(100)',@p0=N'1a',@p1=N'', @sql=N'AddNodeWithPathProc'
```

I tried quite a few variations, but without success.

I'm starting to think that it is not possible to run stored procedures with `ModelContext.[IQueryable].FromSqlRaw`. In my opinion this kind defeats one of the major reasons for `FromSqlRaw` because, for normal select statements, LINQ is normally good enough.

Does anyone know how to use stored procedures in combination with `FromSqlRaw` in EF Core 3.0? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

PS: I know you can execute a stored procedure with `this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(SQL, parameters)`. However, that way it is not possible retrieve any entities that the stored procedure queries.

Comment: Try .ToList() instead of .Single().  .Single() is generating the "TOP(2)" wrapper.

Comment: my temporary workaround for the moment is the following:             this.ModelContext.ExecuteRawSql("EXEC AddNodeWithPathProc @p0, @p1", spParams);
            var createdPath = ModelContext.Paths.FromSqlRaw("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.Path ORDER BY PathID DESC").Single();  However, this is not an acceptable solution for production.

Comment: yes.. ToList() works.. thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 16):

Solution (thanks to David Browne, you should have posted it as an answer):

Replacing Single with ToList works :-)

```
var createdPath = ModelContext.Paths.FromSqlRaw("AddNodeWithPathProc  {0}, {1}", nodeTitle, parentPathString).ToList();
```

Comment: Why there is no exec keyword here, Is stored procedure or dynamic stored procedure?

Answer (score 6):

It is extremely strange… just before a few days ago I have the same problem and follow this post. I had this call:

```
 public IEnumerable<TableChange> GetTableLastChanges(string tableName, string keyColumn, out int synchronizationVersion)
    {
        var parameters = new[] {
            new SqlParameter("@table_name", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = tableName },
            new SqlParameter("@key_column", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = keyColumn },
            new SqlParameter("@synchronization_version", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput, Value = 0 }
        };

        var changes = this.TableChanges.FromSqlRaw("[dbo].[GetTableLastChanges] @table_name, @key_column, @synchronization_version OUTPUT", parameters).ToList();

        synchronizationVersion = Convert.ToInt32(parameters[2].Value);

        return changes;
    }
```

Right now everything is fine and this call works as expected. Therefore I should admit that there is no problem with datasets and params return for EF on Core 3.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result=context.yourmodelclass.FromSqlInterpolated($"StoredProcedureName {param1},{param2}").tolist();
```

You can add multiple parameters if needed.
Note:

- context => your name of database.
- yourmodelclass => the class in models folder you create for fetching the output result from the stored procedure result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not where I can test but I think the following will work:

```
var createdPath = ModelContext.Paths.FromSqlRaw("AddNodeWithPathProc {0}, {1}", parm1 parm2).Single();
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. Just tested it. The sql that is invalid :-( . I believe it has something to do with the sql that is generated. If I check the sql with the profiler it always follows the schema: sp_executesql 'SELECT * FROM {mySqlPassedInMethod}.   I wouldn't know how to to pass in a stored procedure in this code. So either the .net method detects that the passed sql string is for a stored procedure and adapts the generated sql accordingly or there is a way in T-SQL that i don't know of (I'm not an expert)

Answer (score 0):

try to seperate SqlParameter:

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@p0","value");
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@p1","value");

var createdPath = ModelContext.Paths.FromSqlRaw("AddNodeWithPathProc @p0 @p1", param1, 
param2).Single();
```

Comment: posted a solution to your deleted posting below.

Comment: Just tried it and it fails :-(. The error is: "System.InvalidCastException: 'The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.'". There is no sql sent to the sql server (according to sql profiler)

Comment: @jdweng Thanks a lot :)
This solution I have when I log in to my software and download the last updated XML file with last date but I need all histrically data of rates without missing.
So I have another option to set dates and download excel file with the rates, but I don't know how to implement that. run a service on the server? maybe users not going use software for a week so I missed the whole week of exchange rates.

Comment: @ISTech : Look at following page : https://www.boi.org.il/en/Markets/Pages/explainxml.aspx you can add to url a date.  http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml?rdate=20120101

Comment: @ISTech : I updated code below to do a range of date.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer doesn't have the exec keyword, without it the statement raises an error. I copy-pasted the previous answer and it doesn't work without exec.

```
var createdPath = ModelContext.Paths.FromSqlRaw("exec AddNodeWithPathProc  {0}, {1}", nodeTitle, parentPathString).ToList();
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). Also how is this different from previous answers?

Comment: The previous answer doesn't have the exec keyword, without it the statement raises an error. and I copy-paste the previous answer and it doesn't work without exec.