# Why Entity Framework core does not support raw sql query?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was using entity framework 6 in my asp.net application and using raw queries like following:

```
string studentName = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
         "Select studentname from Student where studentid=1").FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I am moving my application to asp.net core, but I could not found raw sql query without using DbSet type.

```
var students = context.Students
                  .FromSql("Select * from Students where Name = 'Bill'")
                  .ToList();
```

But this does not solve my solutions.

Is there any extension that developed to run sql queries?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a stored procedure in EF Core 3.0 via FromSqlRaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207182/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-ef-core-3-0-via-fromsqlraw)

Comment: The real question is why are you using EF to run raw queries? You gain little by using *EF* this way. It would be better to use a micro-ORM like Dapper for this and avoid the overhead. Or just use the properl LINQ query, ie `context.Students.Where(s=>s.Id=1).Select(s=>s.Name).Take(1)`

Comment: @phuzi, the documentation says "The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity type." and it says me can not use raw query. I mean it says me do not use entityframework anymore.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have some complex queries taht related multiple tables. So I was running these queries in legacy versions. So this is a so bad stuation. The developer will not move applications to cere.

Comment: It was a bad situation already, because SqlQuery was used as a quick&dirty fix instead of a permanent solution. You can map entities to views, both in EF 6 and EF Core. That is a *LOT* better than storing complex query strings in your code and far less brittle. In EF Core 3 it gets better with [query/keyless entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) as you no longer have to provide a PK for the query results.

Comment: Besides, joining multiple tables is EF Core's job, based on the relations defined between the entities. This works for most cases except eg reporting queries. Those should become views with EF running on top of the view to select and filter results

Comment: it's chaos. Entity framework developers first offer a feature to people, then remove this feature, leaving people half way.

Comment: You can use the extension method here to create an ad-hoc DbContext for your type: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862#issuecomment-451671168

Comment: But some methods that used in your solution are removed entity framework 3.0. For example `db2.Query<T>()`. We can't keep up with the speed of microsoft :)

Answer (score -2):

I got the following from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql):

> The SqlQuery method on DbSet allows a raw SQL query to be written that will return entity instances. The returned objects will be tracked by the context just as they would be if they were returned by a LINQ query. For example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList();
}
```