# EF Core 3.0 Stored Procedure : Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have gone through this question [How to call a stored procedure in EF Core 3.0 via FromSqlRaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207182/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-ef-core-3-0-via-fromsqlraw). But this is not solving my problem. I am working with a **MySql Database**. In my database there is a stored procedure in which I am inserting some data and then returning this whole table.

My stored procedure code is something like:

```
DELIMITER $$
    Create Procedure InsertDepartments(DName longtext,DLoc longtext)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Departments (DepartmentName, DepartmentLocation) 
    VALUES (Dname, DLoc);
    SELECT * FROM Departments ORDER By Departments.DepartmentId DESC;
END$$
```

As you can see I am trying to take two parameters DName and DLoc. Now in my controller in backend I have tried with something :

```
public JsonResult InsertDepartment([FromBody]Department department)
{
     try
     {
        var deptName = new MySqlParameter("Dname", department.DepartmentName);
        var deptLoc = new MySqlParameter("DLoc", department.DepartmentLocation);

        var departments = _context
          .Departments
          .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE InsertDepartments @Dname , @DLoc", new object[] {deptName, deptLoc})
          .ToList();
     return Json(departments);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       return Json(e.Message);
    }
}
```

But this is failing somehow. The error log returned in PostMan is:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''CSE' , 'DT5'' at line 1"
```

Error Log:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteDictionary[TProperty](JsonConverter`1 converter, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWriteDictionary(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.WriteDictionary(WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleObject(JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, JsonResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.SystemTextJsonResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, JsonResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|27_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Not very familiar with MySql/MariaDB but are you certain you are using the right syntax? I thought they used `CALL` to execute stored procedures?

Comment: Still the same @StephenByrne

Comment: Show us the sql text you are executing. Maybe you can try to copy and paste it in management studio to see the error

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori I don't know which SQL Query you are talking about. But I have added details error log. Can you please check that?

Comment: The error comes from the `return Json(departments)` or the `return Json(e.Message)` ???

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori return Json(e.Message)

Comment: So the problem can be in the value of `department.DepartmentName` or `department.DepartmentLocation`. Maybe they contains a special character you have to escape? Again, try to execute the same sql statement  in [My Sql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following modification :

```
var deptName = new MySqlParameter("@DName", department.DepartmentName);
var deptLoc = new MySqlParameter("@DLoc", department.DepartmentLocation);

var departments = _context
              .Departments
              .FromSqlRaw("CALL InsertDepartments(@DName,@DLoc)", parameters:new[] { deptName, deptLoc })
              .ToList();
```